# Vue CLI3 app, HTML srcset and sizes attributes not supported?

Tags: html, vue.js, responsive-design, vue-loader, vue-cli-3

I am trying to use the `srcset` and `sizes` HTML attributes for responsive images to serve a certain image to a certain screen size for performance optimization and responsive design. But Vue-loader doesn't seem to support them, anyone had a similar issue? If not what could be a possible solution to best optimize the app's performance that is mostly impacted by HD images. 
Below is an example of what i am trying to implement in a .vue template

```
<img srcset="../assets/img-1.jpg 300w,  ../assets/img-1-large.jpg 100vw" 
sizes="(max-width: 56.25em) 20vw, (max-width: 37.5em) 30vw, 300px"
alt="photo 1"
src="../assets/img-1-large.jpg">
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details? "Doesn't seem to support them" does not give us much information about what is, or isn't, happening for you.

Comment: Did you tried this? https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/396#issuecomment-267325098

Comment: I mean they are not applied, the image that gets displayed is the one provided by the default `src` attribute in all screen sizes.

Comment: @Guto, I just tried it now, didn't work for me, unfortunately, this seems to be meant for CLI2 not 3 since it was added in Dec 2016, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @MoSwilam the solution provided in @Guto's link is exactly what you need. Webpack won't parse the `srcset` attribute for files to load via the url-loader so you have to do it manually via `require()`. Can you please add what you tried to your question

Comment: There's a vue-loader PR for this but while it has been merged, it's not in any released version for some reason ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/pull/953

Comment: @Phil, ok so now, the `srcset` attribute is working and rendering my photos, however, the `sizes` which is needed to inform the browser which resolution to use according to a certain screen size attribute, still does NOT work, here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/moswilam/pen/LgLPgP?editors=1010) of my attempt. thanks

Comment: @MoSwilam If providing a Codepen (or any fiddle), at least provide one that points to valid Vue code. Otherwise, it's difficult to determine why your code does not "work".

Comment: I actually tried to do it in codesandbox to have my images added to the assets folder and test it, but i honestly don't know if it's even possible to upload img files to the project setup online. is it ?

Answer (score 6):

So Now its actually working as intended, Thanks to @Guto for his reference, Here is the code that gave me the desired behavior which is to switch the photo's density and resolution according to the screen size and resolution.

```js
let photos = {
  photo1_sm : require('../assets/photo1-sm.jpg'),
  photo1_lg : require('../assets/photo1-lg.jpg')
  }
  
  export default {
    //...
    computed: {
      photos() { return photos }
      }
   }
```

```html
 <img :srcset="`${photos.photo1_sm} 300w,${photos.photo1_lg}1000w`"
   sizes="(max-width: 990px) 20vw, (max-width: 37.5em) 30vw, 300px"
   alt="Photo 1"
   src="../assets/photo1.jpg">
```

PS. I left the `src` attribute in case the browser that the user is using doesn't support the `srcset` or `sizes` attributes
but I actually tested it in chrome dev tools and the photo does change according to the screen size. 
again thanks to all of you one more time, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

My preferred way is to use `v-bind:srcset`.

In example (the same can be applied to `sizes`):

```
<img 
   :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" 
   :srcset="require('@/assets/logo.png') + ' 1x, ' + require('@/assets/logo@2x.png') + ' 2x'"/>
```

Notes:

- Advantage - markup is in its own place and no need to over-complicate JS part of the component
- Disadvantage - string concatenation is not always well-readable
- Usage of `@` vs relative format in the image path is up for you